# How to upload and download to gps

Tags: gps

Do you have a step by step guide on how to upload/download points/wayponts and polylines/routes from a gps?

Comment: which GPS did you have in mind?

Comment: and what are you uploading/downloading to/from?

Comment: Please add some more details on your specific question, gps units have different formats and methods of transferring raw data.

Answer (score 8):

The best tool for working with GPS-data up- and downloads is GPSBabel (http://www.gpsbabel.org/). On that site you will also find examples and documentations.
You can use GPSBabel also via a GUI within Quantum GIS. There are also independent GUIs, I know at least that there is one for Linux. If you're using Windows the Installer includes already a GUI (http://www.gpsbabel.org/download.html).

Answer (score 4):

[DNR Garmin](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/tools/arcview/extensions/DNRGarmin/DNRGarmin.html) is free, and it does both tasks (among others).  Additionally, if you look around the site, you can find out how to accomplish both with this package.  One thing that's very important is that you set the Datum & Zone in DNR Garmin before you tranfer your data.  This software also allows you to work with many file formats and has a few other nice functions as well.  The nicest things about this package (besides being free) is that it's easy to learn & use.

**EDIT / ADDITION TO ORIGINAL POST**

The comments & questions raised by the other users are quite valid.  Some additional details would be helpful in our efforts to assist you.  Depending which GPS unit you are using and which software package you need to interface with, DNR Garmin may or may not not be a fit for your needs.  I found another link [HERE](http://www.dnr.state.mn.us/mis/gis/DNRGPS/DNRGPS.html) that outlines the compatible software environments as well as some of the known issues.  It was last updated 3/5/2012, so this is very current information.  It's a very simple task you're trying to accomplish.  With a little reading, I'm sure you can sort it out in less than 1 hour.

Best of luck & hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I use GPS Babel and EasyGPS. Both are free. GPS Babel allows you not only download/upload, but also may conversions that I use often, like gpx to csv, kml etc. Works in Windows, linux and mac.
Easy GPS has a more polished interface, supports a variety of gps units but only works in windows. You can only save as gpx. The GUI allows you to manipulate you information in an easy way, in order to edit (points tracks routes), delete (points tracks routes), create (points routes).